# App crashes on startup for firebase_admob dependency 0.8.0+4

Tags: flutter, admob

I was using `fiirebase_admob` dependency 0.5.5 which was working great but when I went to release the apk version by flutter build apk --release it gave me error so I had to change the dependency from 0.5.5 to 0.8.0+4 and add API `'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'` in dependency of build>gradle this gave me the app-release.apk but causing app is crashing on startup. So, what should I change my dependency to get the app running smoothly?.

Comment: Di d you get solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: I have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

look for the file project.properties and modify the dependencies there with the versions that the error marks, the file build> gradle is modified each time the packager executes, so it does not keep them.

Comment: where can I find project.properties?

Comment: your_proyect\platforms\android\project.properties